# Nginx - make deny IP in external file

Tags: nginx

I have virtual host looks like below:

```
server {
    server_name *.domainone.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://domaintwo.com/notice.html permanent;

    deny 1.2.3.4/21;
    deny 5.6.7.8/20;
    deny 9.10.11.12/20;

}
```

My `deny` list is too long. How to make the list of deny IP in external file?

I've tried make simple `include file.txt;` but not works.

Comment: How exactly did the `include file.txt;` approach not work?  As that sounds like one of the solutions mentioned in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13917866/4072843

Comment: Nginx can restart but not blocking the IP. I put `file.txt` in `/etc/nginx`

Comment: Could you show what some of the lines in your `file.txt` look like?

Comment: It is absolutely same like above codes. Each line just like `deny 1.2.3.4/21;`, `deny 5.6.7.8/20;` and so on. I just plainly copy it to external file

Comment: show full config of your virtual host, please. it doesn't contain any `satisfy` or `auth_basic` directives, for example?

Comment: I've updated the full virtual host in my question above. The virtual host is very simple and purposely only for static redirection. Yes it doesn't contain `satisfy` or `auth_basic`.

Comment: You've got `rewrite` with redirect that is executed before access check.

Comment: I've tried both before and after `rewrite`. The result still same

Comment: I realized the redirection cannot working together with `deny` no matter if I put as external file or not

Comment: Order of directives appearance has nothing to do with order of execution in nginx (with some exceptions). No matter where you write directives, `rewrite` will always be executed before `allow`/`deny`.